# Perl loop through hash

Tags: perl

I'm trying to parse an API response, and create an array

```
 my $data1 = $value->{_embedded}->{'rh:coll'};
 print(Dumper($data1));
```

output:

```
$VAR1 = [
            {
              '_etag' => {
                           '$oid' => '571e0eb10fdcb17d700e586b'
                         },
              '_id' => 'example.com',
              'server_id' => '1',
              'enabled' => '1'
            },
            {
              '_etag' => {
                           '$oid' => '571e0eb90fdcb17d700e586c'
                         },
              '_id' => 'example10.com',
              'server_id' => '1',
              'enabled' => '1'
            }
          ];
```

I'm able to parse values using

```
print $value->{_embedded}->{'rh:coll'}->[0]->{_id} . "\t\n";
print $value->{_embedded}->{'rh:coll'}->[1]->{_id} . "\t\n";
```

output

```
example.com
example10.com
```

How can I create an array out of website names **if** enabled is set to **1**?

I have tried looping thought this

```
foreach my $x (%$data1) {
        print $x->{_id};
 }
```

Comment: `map {$_->{_id} } grep { $_->{enabled} } @$data1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here `$data1` is array reference, so you should dereference it using `@ {..}`. Probably you want something like this:

```
my @sites;

foreach my $x( @ { $data1 } ) { 
  push( @sites, $x -> {_id} ) if( $x -> {enabled} ); # $x is hash reference
}

# now @sites contain all your sites from API response for which enabled is set to 1.
```